# Adding a file formatter for python logging

Tags: python

I have the following code to write to a file:

```
import logging
log=logging.getLogger('avails')
log_file = 'file.txt'
fh = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(fh)

log.info('hello')
```

This will write the word "hello" to the file `file.txt`. However, I would like to format this, so it is written to the file as follows:

```
'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d@%(funcName)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
```

How would I add this format in so it writes that way to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `formatter` to it so it would be like this:

```
import logging
log=logging.getLogger('avails')
log_file = 'file.txt'
fh = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Add Formatting
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d@%(funcName)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

log.addHandler(fh)
log.info('hello')
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/